# Is it the job of the modelling approach to consider or not consider independence/dependence of features? Or should it be known before-hand?

Tags: regression, correlation

I'm confused,

Is it the job of the modelling approach to consider or not consider independence/dependence of features? Or should it be known before-hand?

If I know nothing about independence/dependence, but my data could have either, then how should this affect the modelling approach that I take?

Comment: You can encode known relations with a prior whose strength reflects your confidence. The weaker the prior, the looser the assumptions, but the more data needed to fit it. What kind of a model are we dealing with?

Comment: @Emre I'm studying data mining on this data set: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/dorothea

Comment: @Emre I'm also wondering, how do sklearn functions "deal with" these kinds of "encodings"? Does sklearn have some built-in way to do these?

Comment: I can also obviously get the correlations using a correlation matrix, right? However, how can I embed this info to modelling techniques? Or perhaps some modelling techniques utilize correlation "under the surface"?

Comment: I don't know anything about molecular biology but it seems representative of the [short, fat data problem](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~banks/218-lectures.dir/dmlect9.pdf) so you will want to make assumptions. Start with a sparsity prior.

Comment: @Emre Well in this case I believe it's impossible to assume correlations, because the features are not know by name. They only have indexing on them.